# What are the different parameters for comparing the various caching frameworks?

Tags: caching

I am currently aware of the following Caching Frameworks:
EHCache, MemCache, Redis, OSCache, DynaCache, JBoss Cache, JCS, Cache4J.

Apart from time taken for accessing the data from the cache, What are the different parameters/attributes for comparing these frameworks. And which framework should one use, and when?

Answer (score 1):

Few things on broad level can be : 
 - Technology you are using 
 - API available for the chosen framework
 - Each of the framework has a unique feature so depending on your application requirement you can pick one of the frameworks.

Description of few as picked from source mentioned below

**Ehcache:**

Ehcache is a java distributed cache for general purpose caching, J2EE and light-weight containers tuned for large size cache objects. It features memory and disk stores, replicate by copy and invalidate, listeners, a gzip caching servlet filter, Fast, Simple.

**Java Caching System (JCS):**

JCS is a distributed caching system written in java for server-side java applications. It is intended to speed up dynamic web applications by providing a means to manage cached data of various dynamic natures. Like any caching system, the JCS is most useful for high read, low put application

**OSCache:**

OSCache is a caching solution that includes a JSP tag library and set of classes to perform fine grained dynamic caching of JSP content, servlet responses or arbitrary objects. It provides both in memory and persistent on disk caches, and can allow your site to continue functioning normally even if the data source is down(for example if an error occurs like your db goes down, you can serve the cached content so people can still surf the site only)

**Cache4J:**

Cache4j is a cache for Java objects that stores objects only in memory (suitable for Russian speaking guys only as there is not documentation in English and the JavaDoc is in Russian also :D).

**Redis:**

Redis can be used for caching sessions and storing simple data structures for fast retrievals which when needed can be used for persistence as well.

It is mainly useful for caching POJO objects only.

Here is an interesting article for further insights :

http://javalandscape.blogspot.in/2009/03/intro-to-cachingcaching-algorithms-and.html